# Calendar Extender reference Ajax Control

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I want to add Calendar Extender Ajax Control to my Project ,
But I don't want to add the whole AjaxControlToolkit as a reference because its to big file,

is there any method to let me just take the Calendar Extender Ajax Control reference and but it in my BIN Folder ?!!

Answer (score 0):

Download the source project which is up on [codeplex](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/) and then strip out what you dont want and rebuild.  Probably not quite so easy as there a lot of shared bits, but it should not be a big task.

OR

if your issue is not the size of the dll, but the ammount of script resource files the page requests, then use the new [control bundles](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2013/07/25/july-2013-release-of-the-ajax-control-toolkit)